# nscollectionview awakeFromNib vs cellForItemAtIndexPath same code displays image differently

Tags: ios, uiimage, aspect-ratio

I was using awakeFromNib to set an image with this code

```
self.cellImage01 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mushroom_risotto.jpg"]];
self.cellImage01.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
self.cellImage01.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.cellImage01.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Then I needed indexPath to get the image info from it's data source so I moved the code from awakeFromNib to cellForItemAtIndexPath.  Now it displays differently

1. it doesn't have the same scaleAspectFit
2. going to landscape changes it to a small slice of the pic.

The small slice image only happens when the cell goes out of view, then back into view.

I'm using cell reuse and that seems to be where things are changing, but I can't access the code for that to see what's going on.

Does anyone know the call stack it goes thru for cell reuse?

Why would the aspect work in awakeFromNib and not in cellForItemAtIndexPath?

The common element here is that cellForItemAtIndexPath calls this first:

```
ArticleCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ArticleCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Edit: I should have noted that it displays properly when called in awakeFromNib.

Comment: Are you using auto layout in viewcontroller which is holding collectionview?

Comment: I just turned off auto layout and it didn't change anything.  I also put this: NSLog(@"contentMode: %ld",(long) self.cellImage01.contentMode);  And it came back as 0 after I set it to 1 inside the awakeFromNib with this: self.cellImage01.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;  This is strange, it's like I can't set it if I use cellForItemAtIndexPath: